# how to do dynamic update for a field of an object in MyBatis

Tags: java, mybatis

I have a class Foo with fields bar, baz, and buz and an XML mapping file:

```
<resultMap id="Foo" type="com.Foo">
        <id column="id" property="id"/>
        <result column="bar" property="bar"/>
        <result column="baz" property="baz"/>
        <result column="buz" property="buz"/>
</resultMap>
```

How would I write a generic update mapper that will allow me to update all records for a non-null value of one of of the fields?

e.g. something like

```
<update id="bulkUpdate" parameterType="com.Foo" useGeneratedKeys='true' keyProperty='id' keyColumn="id">
        UPDATE public.foo set
        <if test="bar!= null">
           bar = #{bar},
        </if>
        <if test="baz!= null">
           baz = #{baz},
        </if>
        <if test="buz!= null">
           buz = #{buz},
        </if>
    </update>
```

Comment: What's your intention? Update an object in database with MyBatis or just update an object in memory?

Comment: @user2395365 There is `<set>` tag. See the [doc](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html#trim-where-set).

Comment: Yes, use the `<set>` tag. That's what is was designed for. Also, you don't need a `<resultMap>` if you are updating; those are for selects.